# Toggle LED in C code with CMSIS not working

Tags: c, button, led, cmsis

I am trying to toggle a LED with C code and CMSIS. However, what happens is that it doesn't toggle the LED, it just turns it on and that's it. It needs to toggle when the button is pressed.

this is my button configuration:

```
//Configure Port C pin 13 (Button)
    RCC->AHBENR |= 0x80000;
    GPIOC->MODER &= ~(00 << 26);
    GPIOC->PUPDR &= ~(01 << 26);
```

this is my Led configuration:

```
RCC->AHBENR |= 0x20000;
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x400;
    GPIOA->OTYPER |= 0x00;
    GPIOA->PUPDR &= ~(00 << 10);
```

and this is the code that i have this far:

```
 //Read pin state of Port C pin 13
      if((GPIOC->IDR & (1<<13)) == 0)
      {
          if(!button_down)
          {
              GPIOA->ODR = 0b0100000;
          }
          button_down = 1;
      }
      else
      {
          button_down = 0;
      }
```

Comment: It *feels like* you should have a `GPIOA->ODR = 0b0000000;` somewhere, but I have no experience with cmsis.

Comment: if((GPIOC->IDR & (1<<13)) == 0)
   {
    if(!button_down)
    {
     GPIOA->ODR = 0b0100000;
    }
    button_down = 1;
   }
   else
   {
    button_down = 0;
    GPIOA->ODR = 0b0000000;
   }

   if((GPIOA->IDR & (1<<10)) == 0)
   {
    GPIOB->ODR = 0b0100000;
   }
   else
   {
    GPIOB->ODR = 0b0000000;
   }

this is my code now, but i'm not sure if it toggles

Comment: `GPIOA->ODR ^= 0b0100000` might do the trick in the code you posted. There are two possible additional problems. First, your bit pattern is only 7 bits. You need to check that to make sure you're toggling the correct bit. Second, if the button has any bounce at all, your code will toggle the LED multiple times for each button press.

Comment: what is toggeling a led?

Comment: Toggle means to change a bit from 0 to 1, or 1 to 0. If the code toggles the bit that controls the LED, the LED turns on and off.

Comment: Thank you. Also what is the best way to add a denounce?